# ¿Qué es o a qué se refieren con OP?

Tags: soporte, glosario

La verdad por todas parte veo las iniciales **OP** pero aún no sé a qué se refiere.
Tengo la sensación que tiene que ver con la persona que pregunta, pero me gustaría saber qué significa realmente.

Comment: Puedes ver todos estos términos de glosario en [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/209901)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **OP = Original Poster**

Hacer referencia al autor (original) de la publicación (post).

---

En la mayoría de los casos se hace referencia a la pregunta.

Un ejemplo *clásico* en los comentarios:

> El **OP** no esta buscando esto.

Entonces se sabe que se refiere al autor de la pregunta.

Comment: Lo importamos de [SO], donde se utiliza muy frecuentemente. Personalmente, prefiero siempre usar "el autor".

Comment: Las iniciales estaban en inglés :P por eso nunca di con el significado :)

Comment: Si fuera portugués podríamos decir que es "O Publicador" :-D

Comment: Hace 1 hora que estoy pensando en frases con "O.P." en español y sólo se me ocurren insultos.

Comment: @Mariano - [OP](https://www.facebook.com/pages/ostias-putas/169696026390672) - ahora que lo dices...